# Can't find OxyPlot.Wpf PlotView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

Using Visual Studio 2013, my XAML code can't seem to find the PlotView in the OxyPlot.Wpf library. 
I have used (not at the same time)

```
xmlns:oxy="OxyPlot.Wpf"
xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
```

There are several different ones referenced in the docs, I'm assuming that worked with different releases. I'm using runtime version v4.0.30319
and version 2014.1.546.0 
Any ideas on what reference I should be using or what else it could be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check your project references and make sure that you have included the libraries `Oxyplot`and `OxyPlot.Wpf`.

Comment: Uhg, thank you @JohnnyQ. OxyPlot.Core was the one.

Answer (score 1):

I got problems while reproducing examples from OxyPlot [documentation page](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-wpf-xaml.html). There is no Oxyplot library in Nuget Package  Browser's search results. There is one similar **Eto.Oxyplot.Wpf**. However, it do NOT contains necessary objects. Thats why try to install prerelease version of Oxyplot using Nuget console:

```
Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf -Pre
```

Three packages will be installed OxyPlot (v4.0.30319), OxyPlot.Wpf, OxyPlot.Xps

And the PlotView objects have to be  there.